# What possible uniform with decoration is my ancestor from New South Wales in the early 1900's wearing?

Tags: 20th-century, 19th-century, identification, uniform, australia

I have found the below picture of my ancestor. It was taken approximately in the early 1900's in New South Wales, Australia.

I don't think he was knighted. I have found a census record that he was a dispatch clerk though. I didn't think the attire would be so complicated for that. Perhaps he was promoted.

What is he wearing?

[image: Man from New South Wales, Australia, early 1900's]

Comment: It doesn't look like he's wearing a uniform - rather a simple suit, shirt and necktie. However, he is obviously wearing some kind of sash with a tassled star and some other decoration, on top of a ribbon with another medal. I'm trying to dig up some information on honours/awards from the period, but not matching anything yet.

Comment: Is it possible that your ancestor had a knighthood?

Comment: I don't think he was knighted . I have found a census record that he was a despatch clerk though. I didn't think the attire would be so complicated for that. Perhaps he was promoted

Comment: It could be a freemason's regalia (or similar organisation), they do have these neck collars and sashes (with a variety of embellishments).

Answer (score 17):

I agree with the comments, it doesn't look military in nature. Looking at various organization, I finally found an item [listed on ebay](http://www.ebay.ie/itm/2-x-Vintage-Masonic-sash-London-KENSAL-GREEN-and-other-MASONIC-COLLECTABLE-/292154688970?hash=item4405c6c5ca:g:Pf8AAOSwlndZHbFz) which seems to match both the wide emblem and the tasseled 8-point star with cross inset.[image]

I've zoomed in on part of the image showing the large emblem on the sash, revealing the motto *Amicitia Amor et Veritas* or in English: "Friendship, Love and Truth". So it appears your ancestor was an [Odd Fellow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odd_Fellows) (no insult intended).

Comment: Excellent find - that must have taken some work.

Comment: Just got a lucky hit on the search phrase. (After eliminating military medals from the era, and some reading on the Organizations in Australia from that time period).Wish I could find the meaning of the star however.